# 403/404 error in specific directory in Apache server

Tags: apache, webserver

I'm running Apache Server 2.4.34 in Ubuntu 18.10. I'm unable to figure out why I can't access resources from the icons/ directory in the root of my server directory (/var/www/http/). The files give a 404 and the directory gives a 403 forbidden

This server is newly set up and all files / directories are owned by www-data. I have other directories (eg. images/) that have identical permissions (771 on the directories, 644 on files) that I can access an index of and all of the files in.

I've searched around a ton and I can find a bunch of stuff about not being able to get to subfolders, but not about a specific folder with the same setup as others. If anything this folder should have looser permissions since I've added specific sections about it in my apache2.conf file.

Below is my apache2.conf and default.conf file minus some commented stuff at the top
**apache2.conf**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
# Testing to see if adding this manually works
<Directory /var/www/html/icons>
    options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    require all granted
</Directory>
#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**default.conf**

```
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advanced for any guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer! I couldn't figure out what was different about the icons/ directory so I did a search inside of all of the files in the /etc/apache2 directory for `icons`, and what do you know, a bunch of files I didn't recognize come up. I Googled "Apache icons directory" and found [this article](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/apache-icons-directory/) that describes how the icons directory is aliased to `/usr/share/apache2/icons/` and can't be overwritten.

I ended up moving the files I needed to that directory because I didn't build the site I'm using and don't want to change all of the icon paths.

Comment: Thank you. This has been driving me nuts all day.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem when I am developing a project. I can not access icons from `/icons` when I am setting these icons in any `img` tag.

But after solving this issue by commenting, putting `#` before the `Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"` from this located file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf`, I had to restart the apache server. As I am using Ubuntu. I restarted apache with the following command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After this, icons are showing in `img` tag from the `/icons` folder.